# Stream to Base64String - Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, casting, base-class-library

Help appreciated in resolving the 'Out of memory exception' from the below source at line return `Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray())`;

```
private static string GetSPFileBinary(ClientContext ctx, string fileUrlPath)
    {
        ctx.RequestTimeout = Int32.MaxValue;
        var spFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrlPath);
        var spFileContent = spFile.OpenBinaryStream();
        ctx.Load(spFile);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        if (spFileContent != null && spFileContent.Value != null)
        {
            spFileContent.Value.CopyTo(stream);
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert the file to base64? How do you intend to use the base64 after you've done so?

Comment: this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702965/convert-a-very-large-binary-file-into-a-base64string-incrementally

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `stream.ToArray()` was executed successfully and `Convert.ToBase64String` crashes, you could always convert a batch to 64 string and store it somewhere from where you can reload it. And then load the converted chunks one-by-one and store them into the result file. If your application crashes on `stream.ToArray()`, then you will need to allow your application to use more memory if available or apply the chunk loading idea when you load from stream as well.

Answer (score 0):

even the below throws the same old 'Out of memory exception', help appreciated.

```
private static string GetSPFileBinary(ClientContext ctx, string fileUrlPath)
    {
        ctx.RequestTimeout = Int32.MaxValue;
        var spFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrlPath);
        var spFileContent = spFile.OpenBinaryStream();
        ctx.Load(spFile);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        if (spFileContent != null && spFileContent.Value != null)
        {
            spFileContent.Value.CopyTo(stream);
        }
         byte[] docBytes = stream.ToArray();            
         return Convert.ToBase64String(docBytes);
    }
```